# Unable to execute jar file on Linux subsystem in Windows

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jar

I'm attempting run a jar file, but am running into the "Unable to access jar file" error.

When I run it from the Windows path (I hope the term is right, am new to this), it runs fine:

```
java -jar /mnt/c/jars/filename.jar <parameter>
```

This runs without any issues.

I downloaded this jar into the Linux filesystem, using wget, into  /home/username/jars.
I checked, and the jar file is there.
Now, when I run:

```
java -jar ~/jars/filename.jar <parameter>
```

I get an error, saying:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/username/jars/filename.jar
```

And I'm getting a similar error when i go into the jars directory and run the command:

```
java -jar filename.jar <parameter>
```

Any ideas as to what could be the problem?

From a suggestion in the comments, i ran:

```
ls -l ~/
```

and I got:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 username username 512 Jan 28 11:29 jars
```

Comment: the jar file permission and owner? is it executable?

Comment: yes, it's executable. I don't think its an issue with that

Comment: The `.jar` file doesn't need to be executable when run with `java`; however, the path to the directory needs to be executable. So check the permissions of `~/jars`.

Comment: I did that. Got -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: Are you sure? That doesn't look like a dictionary.

Comment: i ran "ls -l ~/jars". is that the correct command?

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say "directory". Yes that is the correct command, but if `jars` is a directory, the output should be `drwxrwxrwx`. Yours starts with a `-` as if it is a file.

Comment: changed the command to "ls -l ~/". Updated the result in the main question

Comment: I have been reading (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36002043)) that the command needs the full path name, in your case `/home/username/jars/filename.jar`, meaning, `~` will not do. Can you try that please?

Comment: @Jos, tried the full path, but it gave the same error